# Get size of websites in browser history

Tags: javascript, database, web, data-visualization, browser-history

I need to get data about my browsing history:

1. time spend on a site
2. visit count
3. total amount of visited sites
4. data amount (of each site)

As far as I've seen for three points in the list there exist tools to retrieve the data.
Especially point 4 is very important but I don't know any tool for it …
Does anyone know a tool where I could get this data from?

Comment: What do you mean by data amount? The amount of stuff you downloaded from a site?

Comment: I'm not a web developer so I'll explain it in my words: When I visit a site, every visual information that I could perceive on that site is an amount of data. Does that make sense @RyanWilson?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried Webtime Tracker chrome extension?

Comment: Yes but it doesn't offer the data to export I'm looking for